# How can I point to a 2D array?

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array.

```
int MARIO[4][4];
```

I want to show the values of this array on the screen. The problem is that I don't know how to declare a pointer to a 2D array. Can anyone help?

Comment: Yeah, http://cdecl.org can help. Or better yet, a good C book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ugh, so to answer the *actual* question: `int (*ptrTo2DArr)[4][4];`

Comment: And how can I have the access to the blocks of the array with the pointer?

Comment: The way you access a normal 2D array

Comment: @FatemehEslami What kind of blocks? You can index the array behind the pointer just like you would do so with any other array.

Comment: such as `ptrTo2DArr[1][1]`?

Comment: simply use : 2DArr[1][1]

Comment: No, `(*ptrTo2DArr)[1][2]` or  `(*ptrTo2DArr)[i+1][j]`

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend putting that array as a field (perhaps the only one) of some structure like

```
struct my_2darray_st {
   int mariofield[4][4];
};
```

Then declare your function

```
void myfun(struct my_2darray_st*);
```

and use it as follow:

```
struct my_2darray_st myarr;
memset (&myarr, 0, sizeof(myarr));
myfun(&myarr);
if (myarr.mariofield[3][1] > 0) dosomething();
```

[H2CO3's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20581094/841108) is literally correct and brillant, but I never saw any real code using that, e.g. `void myfun(int (*ptrTo2DArr)[4][4]);`.... In practice, aggregates are very often `struct` in C....

And you could also have a `typedef`  and do

```
 typedef int arr4x4t[4][4];
 void myfun(arr4x4t*);
```

#### addenda

BTW, with modern optimizing compilers there is no penalty at all in using `struct`; more specifically, with the following code:

```
 /* file test2d.c */
 // using a pointer to 2d array
 int f(int (*ptrTo2DArr)[4][4])
 {
   return (*ptrTo2DArr)[0][0] + (*ptrTo2DArr)[1][1]
     + (*ptrTo2DArr)[2][2] + (*ptrTo2DArr)[3][3];
 }

 // using a struct
 struct tab_st {
   int arr[4][4];
 };
 int g(struct tab_st *s) {
   return s->arr[0][0] + s->arr[1][1]
     + s->arr[2][2] + s->arr[3][3];
 }    

 // using a typedef
 typedef int arr4x4t[4][4];
 int h(arr4x4t *t) {
   return (*t)[0][0] + (*t)[1][1]
     + (*t)[2][2] + (*t)[3][3];
 }
```

GCC 4.8.2 (on my Debian/Sid/x86-64, in 64 bits mode) when invoked with `gcc -O2 -S test2d.c` (and you may want to add `-fverbose-asm` option) generates *exactly the same assembly code* for `f` and for `g` and for `h` that is

```
    f:
    .LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    movl    (%rdi), %eax    
    addl    20(%rdi), %eax  
    addl    40(%rdi), %eax  
    addl    60(%rdi), %eax  
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

So there are no performance reason to avoid using `struct`-s. I find using them better, because with  `struct`-s **the C code is much more readable** (even if it might be slightly longer, because you need to name both the structure pointer and the field.). This indeed is only an *opinion*.

<sup>In other words, I am in favor of having only pointers to scalar data (including other pointers) - with a comment or convention telling if it is a pointer to some one-dimensional array or to just one data cell -, or structures or unions. Pointers like `int (*ptrTo2DArr)[4][4]` looks really weird to my eyes</sup>

Comment: Literally never saw a pointer-to-2D array? o.O That surprises me. I'd guess there are people out there who need 3 dimensions, and that's best achieved by this (at least it's better than being a three-star programmer). Actually, I'm pretty sure I've used it in one answer of mine related to 3D rendering, but I don't remember anymore.

Comment: I admit that most of the free software code I looked in are not numerical intensive code... Perhaps such code might happen in some audio or video or signal processing applications (which are not my "cup of tea"; I'm much more interested in non-numerical applications).

Comment: I can understand that, numerics can be boring sometimes :)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to show the values of this array on the screen.

Another way, you can declare a pointer to the first element of the first array and loop through the matrix using it. as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int MARIO[4][4]= { {1,2,3,4} , {5,6,7,8} , {9,10,11,12}, {13,14,15,16} };
    int *ptr;
    ptr = &MARIO[0][0];

    int i;
    for (i=0;i<4*4;i++)
        printf("%d\n",*(ptr+i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A 2d array is an array of pointers, kinda like an illusion, anyway here is a program explaining a way to use a pointer with a 2d array;

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int arr [4][4] = {
        {3,4,3,2}, // [0][0] --> [0][3]
        {4,4,4,4}, // [1][0] --> [1][3]
        {5,6,3,2}, // [2][0] --> [2][3]
        {3,3,3,3} // [3][0] --> [3][3]
    };

    // point to an array of pointers (2d array)
    int (*p)[] = arr;
    printf("%d ", **p);  // **p == arr[0][0] or 3


    printf("%d  \n", (*p)[9]); // (*p)[ index ] treats the 2d array like a 1d array
    // the 9th element is really [2][1]

    // output the array of pointers like it's a 2d array
    int col, row, height = 4;
    for ( row = 0; row < 4; ++row ) {
        for ( col = 0; col < 4; ++col ) {
            printf( "%d", (*p)[row*height+col]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```